# Как запретить доступ к админке

Tags: php, laravel, маршрутизация

В `app/Http/Authenticate.php` добавил такой код

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasRole('admin') {
            return $next($request);    
        }
        else if ($request->user()->hasRole('user'))
        {
            return redirect('404');
        }
        else
            return redirect('/');
    }
```

Пользователь с ролью `user` при попытке пройти по `/admin` получает 404, но, к примеру, `/admin/articles` - открывается

upd: можно ли добавить префикс в одну из групп?

```
//admin routes
    Route::auth();
    Route::group([префикс сюда,'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::group([или сюда,'middleware' => ['role']], function () {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Посоветовал бы пользоваться пакетом [entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

2) Тебе нужно объединить маршруты в группу с префиксом admin, и поставить на него middleware, в случае entrust выглядит так:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
 //тут твои пути остальные
});
```

3) Даже если не будешь использовать пакет, тебе нужно создать middleware и повесить ее на группу

Comment: Я так понял, пакет рассчитан на создание ролей с нуля, некоторые роли на проекте созданы без использования пакетов. Смогу ли я создать доп. роль, используя пакет, но чтобы уже существующие не посыпались?

Comment: @Tarasovych смотря как его внедрить :) тут все от тебя зависит, напиши какую-нибудь функцию как контейнер, которая будет выбирать, какой метод проверки использовать, middleware можешь изменить тоже

Comment: Могу ли я добавить несколько префиксов для группы?

Comment: Я немного дополнил вопрос, есть ли смысл в добавлении префикса для конкретных ролей в пути админки?

Comment: @Tarasovych ты ж можешь в middleware массиовм задавать, не пойму зачем делать так auth же фактически входит  в role, плюс можно писать так , role: admin|user|manager

Comment: В middleware, т. е. в app/Http/Middleware/Role?

Comment: Ну в app/Http/Middleware/Role, ты можешь правки внести,  а вот так настроить:  `Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => [ 'middleware' => ["auth",'role:admin|user']]) ....`